# All phrases except in a tag - regexpr

Tags: regex, preg-replace, preg-match, preg-match-all

I want to create regular expression that marks all phrases except those in `A` tag. 
I want to use it to replace it with link.
Can I dop it with one regular expression?
Here is my failed trial: https://regex101.com/r/3I2qvL/1

Comment: Here's a hacky solution that works: `(?:<a.*?<\/a>)\K|(TEST)`. Demo: https://regex101.com/r/3I2qvL/2. Make sure your discard the empty matches :)

Comment: @degant to get rid of the empty matches, you might use the skip&fail trick `/<a.*?<\/a>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\btest\b/i`. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/3I2qvL/3)

Comment: Thanks @HamZa that's a neat trick. I couldn't figure out why `*SKIP` is needed before `*FAIL`?

Comment: @degant check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24535912) out

Comment: @degant check [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230676/hey-you-yeah-you-post-your-answers-as-answers-not-comments/296481#296481) out

Answer (score 1):

To exclude matches surrounded by the tag match the tagged part first and then throw it away with `\K`. This match should also be supplied with empty string via alternation to match substrings not starting with the tag:

```
(?:<a[^>]+>.*?<\/a>\K|)(^|\s|,|;|:|\.)(Test)($|\s|,|;|\.|\b)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/pUPBQQ/1